# Efficiency of equalsIgnoreCase() versus toUpperCase().equals and toLowerCase().equals

Tags: java, string, performance

The title says it all. My question regards the efficiency of different `String` equivalency methods. I frequently use `.equalsIgnoreCase(String str)` because I just have a thing for it. But I'm beginning to wonder if it may not be the most efficient method for finding equivalency between `Strings`. It seems to me that `.equalsIgnoreCase(String str)` is calling one of the case shifting methods `toUpperCase` or `toLowerCase` then calling `equals` in its definition, but I am likely wrong. So, which of these methods is more efficient in the following situation, or any situation for that matter?

```
int count = 0;//checks for face cards at indexes listed in selectedCards
              // Selected cards is Integer ArrayList

    for(; (count < selectedCards.size() && count < 3); count++)
    {
        if(cardAt(selectedCards.get(count)).rank().equalsIgnoreCase("Queen"))
            count++;
        else if(cardAt(selectedCards.get(count)).rank().equalsIgnoreCase("King"))
            count++;
        if(cardAt(selectedCards.get(count)).rank().equalsIgnoreCase("Jack"))
            count++;
    }

    if(count == 3)
        return true;
    return false;
```

Comment: Did you try benchmarking them yourself?

Comment: @dr_andonuts I have no idea how to do that. I would if I could. I'm just curious.

Comment: I mean, just run each a million times in a loop and compare the results.

Comment: @dr_andonuts I have checked out effieciency questions before out of curiousity, and they always have these really weird variables and numbers and methods and such. What would I be measuring if I were to give it a go myself?

Comment: No, you couldn't move the if statement.

Comment: Probably milliseconds (1/1000 of a second).

Comment: Not me. Here, have an upvote, I'm actually a bit curious about this.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't ask people to explain downvotes. Sometimes there is nothing to explain.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JMH makes microbenchmarking easy:

**Update:**  Set up the input string as a parameter to address the comment from JMH God Alexey Shipilev.  I left the target string constant because OP's use case is to compare input strings to a constant.

```
@State(Benchmark)
public class StrComp {

    @Param({"Queen", "queen", "King"})
    public String input;

    @Benchmark
    public boolean eqIgnoreCase() {
        return input.equalsIgnoreCase("queen");
    }

    @Benchmark
    public boolean eqToLower() {
        return input.toLowerCase().equals("queen");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(".*StrComp.*")
                .mode(Mode.AverageTime)
                .timeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
                .forks(5)
                .warmupIterations(10)
                .measurementIterations(10)
                .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
Benchmark             Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
StrComp.eqIgnoreCase  avgt   50  18.581 ± 0.051  ns/op
StrComp.eqToLower     avgt   50  54.796 ± 0.173  ns/op
```

Updated output with parameter:

```
Benchmark             (input)  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
StrComp.eqIgnoreCase    Queen  avgt   50  17.947 ± 0.205  ns/op
StrComp.eqIgnoreCase    queen  avgt   50  15.553 ± 0.159  ns/op
StrComp.eqIgnoreCase     King  avgt   50   2.968 ± 0.037  ns/op
StrComp.eqToLower       Queen  avgt   50  56.499 ± 0.180  ns/op
StrComp.eqToLower       queen  avgt   50  22.023 ± 0.040  ns/op
StrComp.eqToLower        King  avgt   50  49.174 ± 0.145  ns/op
```

So, eqIgnoreCase is faster but unless you are doing a million comparisons per second, you won't notice any difference.

You can play around and see how the difference would be affected if the first string is already lower case or if the strings are of different lengths, etc.

Anyway, If you want to make your code more "efficient" and also more clear, type-safe and less prone to bugs, don't use strings for things like this.  Use enums.

Deck of cards is so well-suited to implementation by enums, it's frequently used to illustrate the `enum` concept: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enums.html#Card

Comment: Well maybe one day I will need to compare a few billion Strings in a few seconds. Thank you Misha. I honestly don't understand what you did with the main method, but I have always wanted to understand benchmarking, so I guess I have a reason to learn it now. I do understand the results though. A big thank you.

Comment: Main method is telling the JMH framework how to run the benchmarks.  These are just a few of the configuration parameters that can be supplied.  JMH is fantastic.  Check it out.

Comment: Easy to get right, and easy to get wrong. At very least, the inputs should not be constant (see http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_10_ConstantFold.java). And, you need to test same/different lengths to get the full picture. P.S. You are not required to have the `main` method to run this benchmark from CLI.

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev I did try with non-constant strings and the results were identical so I kept it out of the posted answer for conciseness.

Answer (score 17):

Surprisingly, these methods are not equivalent for some strange Unicode reasons:

- `toUpperCase("ß")` returns `"SS"`, i.e., two letters, while `equalsIgnoreCase` works character-wise
- There are characters for which neither `toUpperCase` nor `toLowerCase` is sufficient, you must do both

Concerning efficiency, I'd bet that `equalsIgnoreCase` is way faster, as it doesn't copy any data. It also starts with the length comparison.

Note also that `toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase` are `Locale`-sensitive, while `equalsIgnoreCase` is not. IIRC the performance diminishes if an exotic locale gets used.

### Your use case

The best and simplest optimization would be to normalize the casing beforehand. There's no reason to have a "Queen", a "queen", and a "QueEN" in your data - clean up the input ASAP.

You can also use an `enum` for representing the rank.

I'm afraid, your loop is broken. After any of JQK you skip one card, is that intended???

### Simplified code

Do the following

- use foreach loop to keep it cleaner
- use local variables to avoid repeating complicated expression
- replace `if (x) return true; else return false;` by `return x;`

The code without using `enum`s and early normalization would look like this:

```
int count = 0;
// Whatever Position is
for (Position p : selectedCards) {
    String rank = cardAt(p).rank();
    if (rank.equalsIgnoreCase("Jack")
            || rank.equalsIgnoreCase("Queen")
            || rank.equalsIgnoreCase("King")) {
        ++count;
    if (count > 3) { // Tiny and probably useless optimization.
        return false;
    }
}
return count == 3;
```

Comment: "...normalize the casing beforehand." -- This, IMO, is the right answer.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that issue with the loop. I wasnt paying attention to how I was writing the for-loop. God, i can be so stupid sometimes. I appreciate your answer, and would have marked it as THE answer, but Misha showed the benchmarks, so I went with him.

Comment: @JohnnyCoder I'm fine with it. Benchmarking Java is non-trivial and he did it right.

Answer (score 7):

You can check the code simply yourself (it's included in the SDK).

The .equalsIgnoreCase is faster than toUpperCase().equals()
In Java 8, the code is:

```
while (len-- > 0) {
    char c1 = ta[to++];
    char c2 = pa[po++];
    if (c1 == c2) {
        continue;
    }
    if (ignoreCase) {
        // If characters don't match but case may be ignored,
        // try converting both characters to uppercase.
        // If the results match, then the comparison scan should
        // continue.
        char u1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
        char u2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
        if (u1 == u2) {
            continue;
        }
        // Unfortunately, conversion to uppercase does not work properly
        // for the Georgian alphabet, which has strange rules about case
        // conversion. So we need to make one last check before exiting.
        if (Character.toLowerCase(u1) == Character.toLowerCase(u2)) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
return true;
```

So if the compared strings are actually different, it will be faster than first calling toUpperCase then equals as the toUpperCase will modifiy all the characters.

Also the logic involved in toUpperCase seems to be more complicated than in the comparison loop and it creates a new String object at the end.

But you would need to have a lot of comparison operations to actually see any difference.